# UILabel could not keep track with AVAudioRecorder current recording time

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avaudiorecorder

I'm using `AVAudioRecorder` to record from iPhone, and I have a UILabel to keep track of the current recording time of my AVRecorder.
So I set the `UILabel` text with `AVRecorder`.currentTime and with this format: %.02f
I show me the current time like this: "39.02"

The problem is the last digit after the dot does not updating with current time, it's only updated when I pause the recording. Maybe something like this:

Recording: "39.01" -> "39.11" -> "39.41" (the last digit was not updated)
Paused: "39.48" (the last digit was updated)

It seems like the millisecond digit been updating to fast and the UILabel could not keep track of it. Or is there something I have to do with Rounding a float?

Comment: Are you sure you call your method updating the label every 0.01 sec ?

Comment: Does it not update at all? If so, create an NSTimer that repeats every 0.01 seconds that will call a method that refreshes the text.

Comment: Make sure your updating on the main thread, if not use : dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                
                
            });

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your comments. It's mine silly mistake, I update the label every 0.1 sec. Thanks so much @rdurand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you call your update method every 0.01 second :

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.01 
                                 target: self
                               selector: @selector(updateLabel)
                               userInfo: nil
                                repeats: YES];
```